# Cost function is not converging

Tags: python, machine-learning, perceptron

I am naive in Machine Learning ,following text book (Pyhton Machine Learning ) and online course on coursera . I am trying to implement single perceptron algorithm  on standard iris dataset containing only two classes ('sentosa' and 'versicolor') but error function is not converging .Here is my code :-

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class perceptron(object):

    def __init__(self,a,iter):

        self.a=a
        self.iter=iter

    def fit(self,x,y):

        self.w_=np.zeros(1+x.shape[1])
        self.errors_=[]
        for i in range(self.iter):
            errors = 0
            for xi ,target in zip(x,y):
                update=self.a*(target-self.predict(xi))
                self.w_[1:]=xi*update
                self.w_[0]=update
                errors+=int(update != 0.0)
            self.errors_.append(errors)
            print(self.errors_)
        return self

    def net_input(self,x):

        return np.dot(x,self.w_[1:])

   def predict(self,x):

        return np.where(self.net_input(x)>=0.0,1,-1)


iris=datasets.load_iris()
x=iris.data[:100,:2]
y=iris.target
y=np.where(y==0,-1,1)
ppn=perceptron(a=0.01,iter=10)
ppn.fit(x,y)
plt.plot(range(1, len(ppn.errors_) + 1),ppn.errors_,marker='_')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
plt.ylabel('number of classification')
plt.show()
```

Number of misclassification (errors) remains same in every iteration

Answer (score 2):

These lines are wrong:

```
self.w_[1:]=xi*update
self.w_[0]=update
```

Change them to:

```
self.w_[1:] += update * xi
self.w_[0] += update
```

It also looks like your input implementation is wrong:

```
def net_input(self,x):
    return np.dot(x,self.w_[1:])
```

Should be:

```
return np.dot(X, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]
```

You can see the full implementation on my [github](https://github.com/dtroupe18/BasicPerceptron/blob/master/perceptron.py)

Let me know if that doesn't solve your problem.